# Efficient way to handle string similarity?

Tags: r, stringdist

I got stuck on some string similarity issues.

This is how my data looks like (the original data is huge):

```
SerialNumber                SubSerialID            Date

AGCC0775CFNDA1040TMT775     AVCC0775CFNDA1040     2018/01/08
AGCC0775CFNDA1040           AVCC0775CFNDA1040     2015/12/28
AGCC0775CFNDA10407EC        AVCC0775CFNDA1040     2018/03/17
CH~MT765E~C0765HFNCC1056    BGDC0865HFNKG1043     2019/01/07
2658358                     BGDC0865HFNKG1043     2018/08/09
MT765E~C0765KFNCD1044       C0765KFNCD10          2015/04/07
187A126                     C0765KFNCD10          2017/11/31
```

...

My target is:

```
SerialNumber                SubSerialID            Date 

AGCC0775CFNDA10407EC        AVCC0775CFNDA1040     2018/03/17
CH~MT765E~C0765HFNCC1056    BGDC0865HFNKG1043     2019/01/07
2658358                     BGDC0865HFNKG1043     2018/08/09
MT765E~C0765KFNCD1044       C0765KFNCD10          2015/04/07
187A126                     C0765KFNCD10          2017/11/31
```

...

Serial Numbers `AGCC0775CFNDA1040TMT775`, `AGCC0775CFNDA1040`, and `AGCC0775CFNDA10407EC` are the same thing but caused by mistakes. I want to keep `AGCC0775CFNDA10407EC` because it has the latest date on record. However, I cannot use `SubSerialID` and `Date` directly to filter those Serial Numbers because if will remove `2658358`.

I thought about using `stringdist` to find string similarity as another condition (i.e., filter out by abs (similarity) >1.5 and abs (similarity)<0.5) but cannot figure out an efficient way to handle it. The data it's huge and using for loop is unpragmatic. I got stuck for a while and hopefully, someone can give me some advice or suggestion with this matter.

Comment: I always liked the 31st's of November;-)

Comment: 11/31 is a typo.... :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following reproduces your expected output

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(dist = map2_dbl(SerialNumber, SubSerialID, adist)) %>%
    group_by(SubSerialID) %>%
    filter(all(dist > 5) | Date == max(Date)) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 5 x 4
#  SerialNumber             SubSerialID       Date        dist
#  <chr>                    <chr>             <date>     <dbl>
#1 AGCC0775CFNDA10407EC     AVCC0775CFNDA1040 2018-03-17     4
#2 CH~MT765E~C0765HFNCC1056 BGDC0865HFNKG1043 2019-01-07    15
#3 2658358                  BGDC0865HFNKG1043 2018-08-09    15
#4 MT765E~C0765KFNCD1044    C0765KFNCD10      2015-04-07     9
#5 187A126                  C0765KFNCD10      2017-11-30    11
```

The idea is to keep all entries (per `SubSerialID`) if *all* Levenshtein distances between `SubserialID` and `SerialNumber` are greater than 5. If there is one distance `<= 5`, only keep the row with the largest `Date`. I've kept the `dist` column for debugging; you can remove the column with `select(-dist)`.

I'm not sure how generalisable this is. You will have to play around with the Levenshtein distance threshold (which I set to `5` in this case).

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
"SerialNumber                SubSerialID            Date

AGCC0775CFNDA1040TMT775     AVCC0775CFNDA1040     2018/01/08
AGCC0775CFNDA1040           AVCC0775CFNDA1040     2015/12/28
AGCC0775CFNDA10407EC        AVCC0775CFNDA1040     2018/03/17
CH~MT765E~C0765HFNCC1056    BGDC0865HFNKG1043     2019/01/07
2658358                     BGDC0865HFNKG1043     2018/08/09
MT765E~C0765KFNCD1044       C0765KFNCD10          2015/04/07
187A126                     C0765KFNCD10          2017/11/30", header = T)
```

Comment: Just want to thank you again for showing me this smart idea. I found some special cases and use the same tricks to add one more restriction to find the perfect results I want! Truly learned a lot from you.  @Maurits Evers